# Does <input type="tel"> show telephone number prompts?

Tags: html, forms

My question is a simple one, but I can't seem to find a straight answer.

With , do form autocomplete/password managers show the user's telephone numbers as suggestions? Even if it's only in some browsers/mobile devices.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Only thing it does is when clicked on phone it brings up keypad dialer. Otherwise is like plain text. [developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/tel](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/tel)